# Google Tag Manager only load when connected to Admin

Tags: javascript, google, google-analytics

I've got this weird problem and I just don't know where to look :
I've installed GTM tag on my wordpress site but it seems it's only being loaded when I'm connected as an admin.

How I can tell ? In GTM, i've setup the following simple tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('gtm test html tag');
</script>
```

This code is only triggered when I'm connected to wp-admin.

PS :
Here's other informations that I think may enter in play, but im not sure it's relevant :

- elementor
- wp Rocket
- [autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/autoptimize/)
- Also, when i'm in Preview mode in Google Tag Manager, every tag is triggered even when i'm not connect to wp-admin

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem came from Autoptimize problem : there's an option,
*Also aggregate inline JS?* , should be unchecked

There must be a way to exclude GTM script from Autoptimize, still haven't take a look yet !